# Nutch - fetch new discovered domains

Tags: java, configuration, hadoop, fetch, nutch

We're using nutch 1.6 to crawl web. According to nutch configuration, one should give the seedlist and domain url-filter to traverse across specified domains. However, we want to fetch newly discovered urls if their extension is, let's say, co.uk (only for this extension) We can manage it by adding newly discovered url's domains to a file - or db, whatever -, stop crawler, update domain url-filters and seedlist, then restart it. But how can we do it dynamically, w/o stopping the crawler?

Thanks in advance.

P.S : co.uk domain extension is just an example, we also could add more than one extension to allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

You can add suffixes to domain-urlfilter.txt like "gov.uk" as [DomainURLFilter source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/nutch/nutch-2.0/org/apache/nutch/urlfilter/domain/DomainURLFilter.java.html) on lines 186-189:

```
  if (domainSet.contains(suffix) || domainSet.contains(domain)
    || domainSet.contains(host)) {
    return url;
  }
```

it checks for suffix, domain and host.

Also, you may keep domain urls in an HBase table and manage them via your own filter plugin instead of using DomainURLFilter.